# Select distinct for one column

Tags: sql, db2

I have a compound primary key where the single parts are potentially random. They aren't in any particular order and one can be unique or they can be all the same.

I do not care which row I get. This is like "Just pick one from each group".

My table:

```
KeyPart1 KeyPart2 KeyPart3 colA colB colD
11       21       39                 d1
11       22       39                 d2
12       21       39                 d2
12       22       39                 d3
13       21       38                 d3
13       22       38                 d5
```

Now what I want is to get for each entry in `colD` one row, I do not care which one.

```
KeyPart1 KeyPart2 KeyPart3 colA colB colD
11       21       39                 d1
12       21       39                 d2
12       22       39                 d3
13       22       38                 d5
```

Comment: What Db2 version? What operating-system runs the Db2 server?  ROW_NUMBER() has existed in Db2 for many years.

Comment: DB2 supports `row_number()`:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rows that are unique by colD, you will have to decide which other column values will be discarded. Here, within the `over clause` I have use  `partition by` colD which provides the wanted uniqueness by that column, but the `order by` is arbitrary and you may want to change it to suit your needs.

```
select
       d.*
from (
      select 
             t.*
           , row_number() over (partition by t.colD
                                order by t.KeyPart1,t.KeyPart2,t.KeyPart) as rn
      from yourtable t
     ) d
where d.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work in almost any version of DB2:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by KeyPart1, KeyPart2
                                order by KeyPart1
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you only care about column d, and the first two key parts, then you can use `group by`:

```
select KeyPart1, KeyPart2, min(colD)
from t
group by KeyPart1, KeyPart2;
```

Comment: This does not return distinct values for ColD as asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'order by' if necessary

```
with D as (
select distinct ColdD from yourtable
)
select Y.* from D
inner join lateral
(
   select * from yourtable X
   where X.ColdD =D.ColdD 
   order by X.KeyPart1, X.KeyPart2, X.KeyPart3
   fetch first rows only

) Y on 1=1
```